# how to get the first two bytes from a string in java?

Tags: java, binary, byte

I want to get the first two bytes of a string. For example "hi there" in binary is:

```
01101000 01101001 00100000 01110100 01101000 01100101 01110010 01100101
```

I want the first two bytes in binary, which is in this case is `01101000 01101001`.

Comment: Do you have code to convert string into bytes? If yes then please post it.

Comment: I converted string to binary and that is it.

Comment: You'd do `myString[0]` and `myString[1]`.  The data in a string already *is* binary.  Now, if you want to display those bytes as "character binary" then you need to convert the data -- convert each byte into 8 bytes of character data.  This would be a good beginner's exercise.

Comment: Why not take the first two characters before converting, or you can take the first 17 characters after converting.

Answer (score 0):

Basic approach. Convert to byte array then get the characters you want then format as necesssay.

```
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        StringBuilder result = getBinary("hi there", 2);        
        System.out.println(result.toString());      
        }

    public static StringBuilder getBinary(String str, int numberOfCharactersWanted) {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] byt = str.getBytes();       
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCharactersWanted; i++) {        
            result.append(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(byt[i])).replace(' ', '0')).append(' ');
        }
        return  result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This function takes an input string and the amount of bytes to be converted into bits.
Call it like this:
getBits("hi there",2)

```
public String getBits(String str, int count) {
    String out = ""; //output string
    byte[] content = str.getBytes(); //get the bytes from the input string to convert each byte to bits later
    for(int k=0;k!=count;k++) { //go through the bytes
        String binary = Integer.toBinaryString(content[k]); //convert byte to a bit string
        if(binary.length()<8) { //toBinaryString just outputs necessary bits so we have to add some
            for(int i=0;i<=(8-binary.length());i++) {
                binary = "0"+binary; //add 0 at front
            }
        }
        out = out + binary; //add it to the output string
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: I am geting a error on this line.    String getBits(String str, int count){      the error is                     Syntax error on token "(", ; expected
 Syntax error on token ",", ; expected
 Syntax error on token ")", ; expected
 out cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: this one  String getBits(String str, int count){ is giving me a error